# What ports & outbound domains are used for trigger.io's Reload service?

Tags: trigger.io

I need to deploy a trigger.io app on a wifi net with a heavy firewall. What ports will the net need to have open to function properly?

I'm guessing the answer is ports 80 and 443, with outbound access to trigger.io and maybe (guessing here) reload.trigger.io.

Can anyone confirm the correct access requirements? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All the reload requests are done over HTTPS (port 443), the domains accessed are `trigger.io` and `s3.amazonaws.com`.

That is unless you use the external reload feature, which downloads the resources from the domain you specify.